# Weird behavior with C array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, variable-assignment

I have two arrays `A` and `B` both with the same elements `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` but after doing `A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1` array `B` is getting populated with different number but in reality it should be unchanged.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayPrint(int *arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int A[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int B[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    int n = 3;

    printf("Before \n");

    printf("Array A \n");
    arrayPrint(A, 4);

    printf("Array B \n");
    arrayPrint(B, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (A[i] == B[i]) {
            A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\nAfter \n");

    printf("Array A \n");
    arrayPrint(A, 4);

    printf("Array B \n");
    arrayPrint(B, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Before
Array A
1 2 3 4
Array B
1 2 3 4

After
Array A
1 2 3 4
Array B
5 2 3 4
```

but it should be:

```
Before
Array A
1 2 3 4
Array B
1 2 3 4

After
Array A
1 2 3 4
Array B
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: `A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;` For `i=3` this will result in `A[4] = A[3]+1` which is an illegal access. Array index can only be within range `0..3` for your arrays.

Comment: arrays go from 0 to N-1. You have all your values in the arrays are also wrong (all of them must be one less). NOTE also that the canonical way for iterating is from `i=0 to i<size`, not from `i = 0 to i<= size-1`

Comment: so this problem is happening because two arrays are overlapping after certain index in the memory, am I right?

Comment: It's not that the arrays are overlapping but rather contiguous.  You've gone past the end of `A` into `B`.

Comment: Not because the arrays are overlapping, no.  Their memory is probably adjacent to each other, and overflowing the bounds of one writes into the other, but that is a result of the invalid index being used and is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `B[i]` equal to `4` the expression `A[B[i]]` access memory beyond the array `A` because the valid range of indices for the array `A` is `[0, 3]`.

So it seems the compiler placed the array `B` at once after the array `A` and the first element of the array `B` was changed in this statement

```
A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;
```

for `i` equal to 3.

Instead of your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (A[i] == B[i]) {
        A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

you could write for example

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if ( i != 3 && A[i] == B[i]) {
        A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

Or more precisely

```
const size_t N = sizeof( A ) / sizeof( *A );

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if ( i != N - 1 && A[i] == B[i]) {
        A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: so how to solve this problem that array `B` doesn't get overwritten?

Comment: @altair00 It is unclear do you want to make the array B unchanged like After
Array A
1 2 3 4
Array B
1 2 3 4 When why  is the loop required?

Comment: How to fix it depends on what the fixed version should do, @altair00.  It mostly looks like someone playing tricks for the sake of playing tricks.  You could adjust the array contents by subtracting one from each value (hence using 0..3 instead of 1..4).  Or …

Answer (score 1):

In last iteration of the `for` loop, `i` has the value `3`, so `A[B[i]] = A[i] + 1;` evaluates as `A[4] = A[3] + 1;`.

Storing anything into `A[4]` has undefined behavior. What you observe is consistent with the array `B` being placed in memory immediately after array `A` but this is by no means guaranteed by the C Standard. The behavior is just undefined and anything can happen.